# if, else statement in jquery with php data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So I have a javascript ajax call like so:

```
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/checkout/doCharge",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
          if(data == '1'){
            $("#CheckoutSubmit").prop('disabled', false);
          }
          else{
            $.growl.error({ message: "Your card was declined! Please try again." });
          }
        }
      });
      return false;
```

And the php call is:

```
$response = $this->stripe->charge_card($amount, $card, $desc);

    if($response['paid'] == 'true'){

        echo '1';
    }
    else{
        echo '0';
    }
```

Right now, the `if(data == '1')` is not working. it doesn't throw any error either. I am trying to get data as 1 if the paid response is true and 0 if the response is false.

Comment: alert( data ); console.log( 'data );

Comment: have you tried comparing it with just 1 without the ' ?

Comment: use proper HTTP errors, not homebrewed statuses.

Comment: @JanPeter - Yes I have.

Comment: @moonwave99 - What? give me an answer explaining...

Comment: Ignore him, returning strings like this is fine. HTTP errors should be used for protocol problems.

Comment: Make sure your PHP isn't returning any extra characters, like whitespace characters before or after the `echo`. Check the Network tab of developer tools to see what's actually being returned.

Comment: maybe you get a php error message. beacause any call in your php script is wrong or something like that. I think it is a good idea to debug it with the command alert(data); like @Virus721 told you.

Comment: @Barmar - It gives me two blank lines `(1 and 2)` and then the response is on line `3`

Comment: Sounds like you have some blank lines in your PHP file before `<?php`. Get rid of them, or call `$.trim(data)` in the Javascript.

Comment: No, if there is any problem with the request, you should answer with a proper code [either a 5xx server error, or more likely a 4xx client error in this case]. Then _in the body_ of the response, you may insert whatever you want, but being the response a mere 0/1, it makes little sense. Plus, triggering an error is caught by the `.fail()` handler, which makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$.trim` to remove extraneous whitespace around the response.

```
    success: function(data) {
      data = $.trim(data);
      if(data == '1'){
        $("#CheckoutSubmit").prop('disabled', false);
      }
      else{
        $.growl.error({ message: "Your card was declined! Please try again." });
      }
    }
```